# The datapicker module is not closing when dates are selected

Tags: javascript, datepicker, sharepoint-2016

I have below code, which allows the user to select weekDays only.
However, the datepicker module is not closing when you select the dates nor refreshing.

I am trying to add the onClose: function() but not much luck :(
Please advise.

```
NWF.FormFiller.Events.RegisterAfterReady(function (){
NWF$('.nf-date-picker').datepicker('option',
  {
  minDate: 0,  
  maxDate: '+2y',  
  beforeShowDay: NWF$.datepicker.noWeekends,  
  onSelect: function(datestr){startdate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');}
  onClose: function() {$(datestr).trigger('change');}
  });  
});
```

Comment: Maybe try with this `onSelect: function(datestr){startdate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');}()`

Comment: @MohhamadHasham that does not work ...

Comment: I suspect that  `onSelect()` you are not calling anything to close the dropdown.

Comment: @MohhamadHasham not sure, I only added this `onClose: function() {$(datestr).trigger('change');}` to test it but does not work either ....